# Literate Haskell Source for Haskell School of Expression. Confusion

Tags: haskell

Below is an example from the [source code](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/hudak/SOE/) for the book "Haskell School of Expression".

I have not seen this source code format explained in the book and it does not make sense to me.

Why are lines marked with `<` not necessarily executable ?

Everything in this code seems executable to me.

How should I interpret the `<`, `>` symbols ?

Why not just simply use simple Haskell code ? What are these extra symbols all about ?

How can I translate this code to simple Haskell ?

I searched the net before asking but have not really found much on this topic.

```
This code was automatically extracted from a .lhs file that
uses the following convention:

-- lines beginning with ">" are executable
-- lines beginning with "<" are in the text,
     but not necessarily executable
-- lines beginning with "|" are also in the text,
     but are often just expressions or code fragments.

< reactimate :: String -> Behavior Graphic -> IO ()

< color1 :: Behavior Color
< color1 = red `untilB` (lbp ->> blue)

< ball1 :: Behavior Picture
< ball1 = paint color1 circ

< circ :: Behavior Region
< circ = translate (cos time, sin time) (ell 0.2 0.2)

< test beh = reactimate "FAL Test" (lift1 picToGraphic beh)

< color1r = red  `untilB` lbp ->>
<           blue `untilB` lbp ->>
<           color1r

< color2 = red `untilB` ((lbp ->> blue) .|. (key ->> yellow))

< color2r = red `untilB` colorEvent where
<           colorEvent = (lbp ->> blue   `untilB` colorEvent) .|. 
<                        (key ->> yellow `untilB` colorEvent)

< color2h = red `switch` ((lbp ->> blue) .|. (key ->> yellow))

< color1h = red `switch` (lbp `withElem_` cycle [blue,red])

< color3 = white `switch` (key =>> \c ->
<            case c of 'R' -> red
<                      'B' -> blue
<                      'Y' -> yellow 
<                      _   -> white  )

< color4 = white `switch` ((key `snapshot` color4) =>> \(c,old) ->
<            case c of 'R' -> red
<                      'B' -> blue
<                      'Y' -> yellow 
<                      _   -> lift0 old)

< color5 = red `untilB` (when (time >* 5) ->> blue)

< s,v :: Behavior Float
< s = s0 + integral v
< v = v0 + integral f

< ball2 = paint red (translate (x,y) (ell 0.2 0.2))
<        where g =  -4
<              x =  -3 + integral 0.5
<              y = 1.5 + integral v
<              v = integral g `switch` (hit `snapshot_` v =>> \v'->
<                  lift0 (-v') + integral g)
<              hit = when (y <* -1.5)

> module Fal where
>
> import SOE hiding (Region, Event)
> import qualified SOE as G (Region, Event)
> import Animation (picToGraphic)
> import Shape
> import Picture
> import Memo1

> import Draw (xWin,yWin,intToFloat)
> -- import Word (word32ToInt)
> import Control.Concurrent.Chan

> infixr 1 =>>, ->>
> infixr 1 `untilB`, `switch`, `stepAccum`, `step`
> infixl 0 .|.
> infixr 4 <*, >*
> infixr 3 &&*
> infixr 2 ||*

> type Time = Float

< data G.Event 
<   = Key       { char :: Char, isDown :: Bool }
<   | Button    { pt :: Point, isLeft, isDown :: Bool }
<   | MouseMove { pt :: Point }
<   | Resize
<   | Closed
< deriving Show 

> type UserAction = G.Event

< data G.Event 
<   = Key Char Bool
<   | Button Point Bool Bool
<   | MouseMove Point
<   | Resize
<   | Closed
< deriving Show 

< k = Key 'a' True
< b = Button (0,0) True False

< k = Key { char = 'a', isDown = True }
< b = Button { pt = (0,0), isLeft = True, isDown = False }

< k = Key { isDown = True, char = 'a' }
< b = Button { isLeft = True, isDown = False, pt = (0,0) }

| char k   ==> 'a'
| char b   ==> error ...
| isDown k ==> True
| isDown b ==> False

| k { char = 'b' } ==> Key 'b' True

< incr (Button { pt = (x,y) }) = (x+1,y+1)

> newtype Behavior1 a 
>   = Behavior1 ([(UserAction,Time)] -> Time -> a)

> inList :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool

> inList xs y = elem y xs

> result1 :: [Bool]
> result1 = map (inList xs) ys

> xs = [2,4,6,8,10] :: [Int]
> ys = [3,6,9]      :: [Int]

> result2 :: [Bool]
> result2 = manyInList xs ys
>
> manyInList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Bool]
> manyInList [] _ = []
> manyInList _ [] = []
> manyInList (x:xs) (y:ys) =
>   if x<y then          manyInList xs (y:ys)
>          else (x==y) : manyInList (x:xs) ys

< bf :: [(UserAction,Time)] -> Time -> a

< inList :: [Int] -> Int -> Bool

> newtype Behavior2 a 
>   = Behavior2 ([(UserAction,Time)] -> [Time] -> [a])

< manyInList :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Bool]

> newtype Behavior3 a 
>   = Behavior3 ([UserAction] -> [Time] -> [a])

> newtype Behavior4 a 
>   = Behavior4 ([Maybe UserAction] -> [Time] -> [a])

> newtype Behavior a 
>   = Behavior (([Maybe UserAction],[Time]) -> [a])

< type Event a = Behavior (Maybe a)

> newtype Event a 
>   = Event (([Maybe UserAction],[Time]) -> [Maybe a])

> time :: Behavior Time
> time = Behavior (\(_,ts) -> ts)

> constB :: a -> Behavior a
> constB x = Behavior (\_ -> repeat x)

< red, blue :: Behavior Color
< red    = constB Red
< blue   = constB Blue

> ($*) :: Behavior (a->b) -> Behavior a -> Behavior b
> Behavior ff $* Behavior fb
>   = Behavior (\uts -> zipWith ($) (ff uts) (fb uts))

> lift0 :: a -> Behavior a
> lift0 = constB

> lift1 :: (a -> b) -> (Behavior a -> Behavior b)
> lift1 f b1 
>   = lift0 f $* b1

> lift2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (Behavior a -> Behavior b -> Behavior c)
> lift2 f b1 b2 
>   = lift1 f b1 $* b2

> lift3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> 
>          (Behavior a -> Behavior b -> Behavior c -> Behavior d)
> lift3 f b1 b2 b3 
>   = lift2 f b1 b2 $* b3

> pairB :: Behavior a -> Behavior b -> Behavior (a,b)
> pairB = lift2 (,)

> fstB :: Behavior (a,b) -> Behavior a
> fstB  = lift1 fst
> sndB :: Behavior (a,b) -> Behavior b
> sndB  = lift1 snd

> paint :: Behavior Color -> Behavior Region -> Behavior Picture
> paint = lift2 Region

> red, blue, yellow, green, white, black :: Behavior Color
> red    = lift0 Red
> blue   = lift0 Blue
> yellow = lift0 Yellow 
> green  = lift0 Green
> white  = lift0 White
> black  = lift0 Black

> shape :: Behavior Shape -> Behavior Region
> shape   = lift1 Shape

> ell, rec :: Behavior Float -> Behavior Float -> Behavior Region
> ell x y = shape (lift2 Ellipse   x y) 
> rec x y = shape (lift2 Rectangle x y)

> translate :: (Behavior Float, Behavior Float) 
>              -> Behavior Region -> Behavior Region
> translate (Behavior fx, Behavior fy) (Behavior fp)
>       = Behavior (\uts -> zipWith3 aux (fx uts) (fy uts) (fp uts))
>         where aux x y p = Translate (x,y) p

> (>*),(<*) :: Ord a => Behavior a -> Behavior a -> Behavior Bool
> (>*) = lift2 (>)
> (<*) = lift2 (<)

> (&&*),(||*) :: Behavior Bool -> Behavior Bool -> Behavior Bool
> (&&*) = lift2 (&&)
> (||*) = lift2 (||)

> over :: Behavior Picture -> Behavior Picture -> Behavior Picture
> over = lift2 Over

> instance Fractional a => Fractional (Behavior a) where
>   (/) = lift2 (/)
>   fromRational = lift0 . fromRational

> instance Num a => Num (Behavior a) where
>   (+) = lift2 (+)
>   (*) = lift2 (*)
>   negate = lift1 negate
>   abs = lift1 abs
>   signum = lift1 signum
>   fromInteger = lift0 . fromInteger

> instance Show (Behavior a)  where
>   showsPrec n a s = "<< Behavior >>"

> instance Eq (Behavior a) where
>   a1 == a2 = error "Can't compare behaviors."

> instance Floating a => Floating (Behavior a) where
>   pi    = lift0 pi
>   sqrt  = lift1 sqrt
>   exp   = lift1 exp
>   log   = lift1 log
>   sin   = lift1 sin
>   cos   = lift1 cos
>   tan   = lift1 tan
>   asin  = lift1 asin
>   acos  = lift1 acos
>   atan  = lift1 atan
>   sinh  = lift1 sinh
>   cosh  = lift1 cosh
>   tanh  = lift1 tanh
>   asinh = lift1 asinh
>   acosh = lift1 acosh
>   atanh = lift1 atanh

>-- untilB, switch :: Behavior a -> Event (Behavior a) -> Behavior a

> Behavior fb `untilB` Event fe =
>   memoB $ Behavior (\uts@(us,ts) -> loop us ts (fe uts) (fb uts))
>     where loop (_:us) (_:ts) ~(e:es) (b:bs) =
>             b : case e of 
>                   Nothing             -> loop us ts es bs
>                   Just (Behavior fb') -> fb' (us,ts)

> memoB :: Behavior a -> Behavior a

 memoB = id

> memoB (Behavior fb) = Behavior (memo1 fb)

> Behavior fb `switch` Event fe =
>   memoB $ Behavior (\uts@(us,ts) -> loop us ts (fe uts) (fb uts))
>     where loop (_:us) (_:ts) ~(e:es) ~(b:bs) = 
>             b : case e of 
>                   Nothing             -> loop us ts es bs
>                   Just (Behavior fb') -> loop us ts es (fb' (us,ts))

> lbp :: Event ()
> lbp = Event (\(uas,_) -> map getlbp uas)
>       where getlbp (Just (Button _ True True)) = Just ()
>             getlbp _                           = Nothing

< color1 :: Behavior Color
< color1 = red `untilB` lbp ->> blue

< (->>) :: Event () -> Behavior Color -> Event (Behavior Color)

< (->>) :: Event a -> b -> Event b

> (=>>) :: Event a -> (a->b) -> Event b

< Event fe =>> f = Event (\uts -> map aux (fe uts))
<   where aux (Just a) = Just (f a)
<         aux Nothing  = Nothing

> Event fe =>> f = Event (map (fmap f) . fe)

> e ->> v = e =>> \_ -> v

> while :: Behavior Bool -> Event ()

> while (Behavior fb) 
>   = Event (\uts -> map aux (fb uts))
>     where aux True  = Just ()
>           aux False = Nothing

> unique :: (Show a, Eq a) => Event a -> Event a
> unique (Event fe) =
>       Event (\uts -> aux (fe uts))
>       where aux xs = zipWith remdup (Nothing:xs) xs
>             remdup x y | x==y      = Nothing
>                        | otherwise = y

> when :: Behavior Bool -> Event ()
> when = unique . while

> integral :: Behavior Float -> Behavior Float
> integral (Behavior fb)
>   = Behavior (\uts@(us,t:ts) -> 0 : loop t 0 ts (fb uts))
>       where loop t0 acc (t1:ts) (a:as) 
>                  = let acc' = acc + (t1-t0)*a
>                    in acc' : loop t1 acc' ts as

> color1 :: Behavior Color
> color1 = red `untilB` lbp ->> blue

> uas = cycle [Nothing, Just (Button (0,0) True True), Nothing]
> ts  = [1,2 ..] :: [Time]

> stream1 = let Behavior fb = color1
>           in take 3 (fb (uas,ts))

| lbp (uas,ts)

| let Event fe = lbp 
| in fe (uas,ts) 

| (lbp ->> blue) (uas,ts)
| ===> (lbp =>> \_-> blue) (uas,ts)
| ===> (map (fmap (\_-> blue)) . fe) (uas,ts)
| !!!    where fe (uas,_) = map getlbp uas
| ===> map (fmap (\_-> blue)) (fe (uas,ts))
| !!!    where fe (uas,_) = map getlbp uas
| ===> map (fmap (\_-> blue)) (Nothing : Just() : Nothing : ...)
| ===> Nothing : Just blue : Nothing : ...

< tuas  = tail uas
< ttuas = tail (tail uas)
< tts   = tail ts
< ttts  = tail (tail ts)

| (red `switch` (lbp ->> blue)) (uas,ts)
| ===> loop uas ts ((lbp ->> blue) (uas,ts)) (red (uas,ts))
| ===> loop uas ts (Nothing : Just blue : Nothing : ...) (red (uas,ts))
| ===> loop uas ts (Nothing : Just blue : Nothing : ...) (repeat Red)
| ===> loop uas ts (Nothing : Just blue : Nothing : ...) [Red ..]
| ===> Red : loop tuas tts (Just blue : Nothing : ...) [Red ..]
| ===> Red : Red : loop ttuas ttts (Nothing : ...) (blue (ttuas,ttts))
| ===> Red : Red : loop ttuas ttts (Nothing : ...) [Blue..]
| ===> Red : Red : Blue : ...

> test beh = reactimate "FAL Test" (lift1 picToGraphic beh)

> cball1   = paint color1  circ
> cball1r  = paint color1r circ
> cball1h  = paint color1h circ
> cball2   = paint color2  circ
> cball2r  = paint color2r circ
> cball2h  = paint color2h circ
> cball3   = paint color3  circ
> cball4   = paint color4  circ
> cball5   = paint color5  circ
> circ     = translate (cos time, sin time) (ell 0.2 0.2)

> ball1 :: Behavior Picture
> ball1 = paint color1 circ

> color1r = red  `untilB` lbp ->>
>           blue `untilB` lbp ->>
>           color1r

> color2r = red `untilB` colorEvent where
>           colorEvent = (lbp ->> blue   `untilB` colorEvent) .|. 
>                        (key ->> yellow `untilB` colorEvent)

> color2h = red `switch` ((lbp ->> blue) .|. (key ->> yellow))

> color5 = red `untilB` when (time >* 5) ->> blue

> sim1 = drawIt "Bouncing Ball" 
>               (b `Over` Region White (Shape (Rectangle 6 5)))

> drawIt :: String -> Picture -> IO ()
> drawIt s p
>   = runGraphics (
>     do w <- openWindow s (xWin,yWin)
>        drawPic w p
>        spaceClose w
>     )

> b :: Picture
> b = let Behavior f = ball2Sim
>     in foldr Over EmptyPic 
>          (take 100 (f (repeat Nothing, [0.0, 0.1 ..])))

> ball2Sim = paint red (translate (x,y) (ell 0.08 0.08))
>        where g =  -4
>              x =  -3 + integral 0.7
>              y = 1.5 + integral v
>              v = integral g `switch` (hit `snapshot_` v =>> \v'->
>                  lift0 (-v') + integral g)
>              hit = when (y <* -1.5)

> ball2 = paint red (translate (x,y) (ell 0.2 0.2))
>        where g =  -4
>              x =  -3 + integral 0.5
>              y = 1.5 + integral v
>              v = integral g `switch` (hit `snapshot_` v =>> \v'->
>                  lift0 (-v') + integral g)
>              hit = when (y <* -1.5)

> sim2 = drawIt "Paddleball!!" 
>               (pb `Over` Region White (Shape (Rectangle 6 5)))

> pb :: Picture
> pb = let Behavior f = paddleball 2
>      in f (repeat Nothing, cycle [0.1, 0.2 ..]) !! 3

> color1h = red `switch` (lbp `withElem_` cycle [blue,red])

> withElem  :: Event a -> [b] -> Event (a,b)
> withElem (Event fe) bs = Event (\uts -> loop (fe uts) bs)
>   where loop (Just a  : evs) (b:bs) = Just (a,b) : loop evs bs
>         loop (Nothing : evs)    bs  = Nothing    : loop evs bs

> withElem_ :: Event a -> [b] -> Event b
> withElem_ e bs = e `withElem` bs =>> snd

> color2 = red `untilB` (lbp ->> blue .|. key ->> yellow)

> (.|.) :: Event a -> Event a -> Event a
> Event fe1 .|. Event fe2 
>   = Event (\uts -> zipWith aux (fe1 uts) (fe2 uts))
>       where aux Nothing  Nothing  = Nothing
>             aux (Just x) _        = Just x
>             aux _        (Just y) = Just y

> key :: Event Char
> key = Event (\(uas,_) -> map getkey uas)
>       where getkey (Just (Key ch True)) = Just ch
>             getkey _                    = Nothing

> color3 = white `switch` (key =>> \c ->
>            case c of 'R' -> red
>                      'B' -> blue
>                      'Y' -> yellow 
>                      _   -> white  )

> color4 = white `switch` (key `snapshot` color4 =>> \(c,old) ->
>            case c of 'R' -> red
>                      'B' -> blue
>                      'Y' -> yellow 
>                      _   -> lift0 old)

> snapshot :: Event a -> Behavior b -> Event (a,b)
> Event fe `snapshot` Behavior fb
>   = Event (\uts -> zipWith' aux (fe uts) (fb uts))
>       where aux (Just x) y = Just (x, y)
>             aux Nothing  _ = Nothing

> zipWith' f ~(x:xs) ~(y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys

> snapshot_ :: Event a -> Behavior b -> Event b
> snapshot_ e b = e `snapshot` b =>> snd

< b1 = b0 `switch` (e `snapshot` b1 =>> b2)

> step :: a -> Event a -> Behavior a

> a `step` e = constB a `switch` e =>> constB

> stepAccum :: a -> Event (a->a) -> Behavior a

> a `stepAccum` e = b 
>    where b = a `step` (e `snapshot` b =>> uncurry ($))

> counter = 0 `stepAccum` lbp ->> (+1)

> stream2 = let Behavior fb = counter
>           in take 20 (fb (uas,ts))

> mm :: Event Coordinate
> mm = Event (\(uas,_) -> map getmm uas)
>      where getmm (Just (MouseMove pt)) = Just (gPtToPt pt)
>            getmm _                     = Nothing
>

> gPtToPt :: (Int, Int) -> Coordinate
> gPtToPt (x,y) = ( pixelToInch (x - 300)
>                 , pixelToInch (250 - y) )
>
> pixelToInch  :: Int -> Float
> pixelToInch n = intToFloat n / 100

> mouse :: (Behavior Float, Behavior Float)

> mouse = (fstB m, sndB m)
>           where m = (0,0) `step` mm

< translate :: (Behavior Float, Behavior Float) 
<              -> Behavior Region -> Behavior Region

> ball3 = paint color4 circ3
> circ3 = translate mouse (ell 0.2 0.2)

> paddleball vel = walls `over` paddle `over` pball vel

> walls = let upper = paint blue (translate ( 0,1.7) (rec 4.4 0.05))
>             left  = paint blue (translate (-2.2,0) (rec 0.05 3.4))
>             right = paint blue (translate ( 2.2,0) (rec 0.05 3.4))
>         in upper `over` left `over` right

> paddle = paint red (translate (fst mouse, -1.7) (rec 0.5 0.05))

> pball vel =
>  let xvel    = vel `stepAccum` xbounce ->> negate
>      xpos    = integral xvel
>      xbounce = when (xpos >*  2 ||* xpos <* -2)
>      yvel    = vel `stepAccum` ybounce ->> negate
>      ypos    = integral yvel
>      ybounce = when (ypos >* 1.5 
>                ||* ypos      `between` (-2.0,-1.5) &&*
>                    fst mouse `between` (xpos-0.25,xpos+0.25))
>  in paint yellow (translate (xpos, ypos) (ell 0.2 0.2))

> x `between` (a,b) = x >* a &&* x <* b

< timeTrans :: Behavior Time -> Behavior a -> Behavior a

> reactimate :: String -> Behavior Graphic -> IO ()
> reactimate title franProg
>   = runGraphics $
>     do w <- openWindowEx title (Just (0,0)) (Just (xWin,yWin))
>               drawBufferedGraphic
>        (us,ts,addEvents) <- windowUser w
>        addEvents
>        let drawPic (Just g) = 
>              do setGraphic w g
>                 quit <- addEvents
>                 if quit 
>                   then return True
>                   else return False
>            drawPic Nothing  = return False
>        let Event fe = sample `snapshot_` franProg
>        run drawPic (fe (us,ts))
>        closeWindow w
>   where
>     run f (x:xs) = do
>       quit <- f x
>       if quit
>         then return ()
>         else run f xs
>     run f [] = return ()
>
> sample :: Event ()
> sample = Event (\(us,_) -> map aux us)
>   where aux Nothing  = Just ()
>         aux (Just _) = Nothing

> windowUser :: Window -> IO ([Maybe UserAction], [Time], IO Bool)
> windowUser w
>   = do (evs, addEv) <- makeStream
>        t0 <- timeGetTime
>        let addEvents =
>              let loop rt = do
>                    mev <- maybeGetWindowEvent w
>                    case mev of
>                      Nothing -> return False
>                      Just e  -> case e of
>                         Key ' ' True -> return True
>                         Closed -> return True
>                         _ -> addEv (rt, Just e) >> loop rt
>              in do t <- timeGetTime
>                    let rt = w32ToTime (t-t0)
>                    quit <- loop rt
>                    addEv (rt, Nothing)
>                    return quit
>        return (map snd evs, map fst evs, addEvents)

> w32ToTime t = intToFloat (fromInteger (toInteger t)) / 1000

> makeStream :: IO ([a], a -> IO ())
> makeStream = do
>   ch <- newChan
>   contents <- getChanContents ch
>   return (contents, writeChan ch)

< Event fe =>> f = Event (map (aux f) . fe)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming) page on Literate Haskell?

Comment: You can also generate de-litted, processed Haskell source from a `.lhs` file with `ghc -E filename.lhs`.  It may contain extra whitespace, though.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did look and I did not understand it.

Comment: In other words, I did not understand how I should read these `.lhs` files.

Comment: I mean, that website did not really answer the questions I asked.

Comment: A literate Haskell file is one that merges documentation and source code. Usually there is a marker of some sorts that delimits code from documentation, in this case the `>` symbol indicates a line that contains valid code, while any other line is considered a comment.  The more usual form you'll see in the wild uses the LaTeX style of `\begin{code}` and `\end{code}`. Alternatively, think of it as having comments and code inverted. Normally you would prefix a comment with `--` in front of the line and everything else is code but here comments are the default and code must be prefixed with `>`.

Comment: Thank you, what confused me was the `<` and `|` about which I was thinking that are also somehow part of the `.lhs` syntax but now I start to realise that they are just invented by the author and have nothing to do with the `.lhs` syntax.

Comment: But now all starts to be clear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THe point of the `<` lines is to show you the definition of or alternative definitions of a function / type.

In the file `Fal.lhs` there are three definitions of the `color1` function:

```
< color1 :: Behavior Color
< color1 = red `untilB` (lbp ->> blue)

< color1 :: Behavior Color
< color1 = red `untilB` lbp ->> blue

> color1 :: Behavior Color
> color1 = red `untilB` lbp ->> blue
```

Only the third one will be processed by `ghc` and `ghci`. The first two are just there to show different attempts / alternative ways of defining it.

In the file `MDL.lhs` the `<` syntax is used to show you definitions from an imported module - e.g.:

```
> import Haskore ( MidiFile(..), MidiChannel, ProgNum, MEvent,
>                  MFType, Velocity, MEvent(..), MidiEvent(..),
>                  MetaEvent(..), Division(..), MTempo,
>                  outputMidiFile )

< data MidiFile = MidiFile MFType Division [Track]
<      deriving (Show, Eq)
```

In this case the type `MidiFile` is defined in and imported from the `Haskore` module and the `<` lines are there just as a convenience to show you what the definition is.

In any case, any lines of a `.lhs` file not beginning with a `>` are ignored by `ghc` and `ghci`.